# Split value present in one Column by specific character

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a Data-frame which contain two column.

On the first column (Motif_name) my value look like that :

> > Motif_Name_xx/Description/Homer

Second column just contain a score.

I'm trying to split my first column by '/' and conserve the first element.

Basically what I tried :

```
   df=df['Motif_name'].str.split('/').str[1]
```

Here the problem is that my data-frame is replaced :

```
   print(df)
   0      Motif_1
   1      Motif_2
```

I lost the header and the second column...

I expect to have a data-frame like that :

```
   Motif_name       Score
 0 Motif_Name_xx1  0.001
 1 Motif_Name_xx2  0.05
 2 Motif_Name_xx3  0.02
 3 Motif_Name_xx4  0.01
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems need parameter `n=1` for split by first `/` and `str[0]` for get first value of lists (python count from `0`) and then assign it to same column:

```
df['Motif_name'] = df['Motif_name'].str.split('/', n=1).str[0]
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I just also find the solution. The [1] was a mistake in my exemple. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just see the solution when I was editing my question, so if someone else need the answer :

```
 EF1a_R1_df['Motif_name']=EF1a_R1_df['Motif_name'].str.split('/').str[0]
```

Basically, in place to replace the all data-frame, just replace the column and it work well.